# What is the $HOME environment variable in github actions?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, github-actions

While trying to create a github action to build my webapp with [trunk](https://trunkrs.dev/), I discovered an error in the logs of my github action: rust is not well installed !

So I investigated and found that these where the environment variable git workflows use when starting a container:

https://pastebin.com/xGMNhKLa

In particular:

```
HOME=/github/home
```

That is why rust was not found: the home is not /root, and the .rustup folder was in /root in my container
But why ?
Do I need to use sudo in my docker entrypoint ?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)